# NDWI from Landsat-8 imagery

Tags: landsat-8, normalized-difference-water-index

I am trying to calculate NDWI from Landsat-8 Band3(range:-113 to 11785) and Band5(range -89 to 12960) but the range of the resultant NDWI image is not valid (range: -215.181 to 1151.02). What is the possible workaround?

Comment: And what makes you think that the range that you are seeing in the resultant image is incorrect? Negative input values in a NDWI calculation can lead to all sorts of strange values, however, the main bulk of your values should be between -1 and 1. Perhaps take a look at the distribution of values?

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen NDWI valid range is between -1 to 1. Secondly, when I check the pixel value of the water bodies its incorrect. The pixel value of water should be greater than 0.

Comment: And are you using atmospherically corrected data?

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen Yes I am using Landsat-8 surface reflectance product from USGS.

Comment: Well - you start with some overcorrected values, which you should surely mask. Surface reflectance cannot be lower 0 and all areas where it is less than 0 should be treated as invalid. Furthermore, the assumption that your water will necessarily be strictly above 0 in NDWI is risky, due to sunglints and mixed pixels.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen I have already tried this strategy.But, when I try to mask out all values less than 0 the pixels over water features disappear in NIR band.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using poorly atmospherically corrected data. I suggest either atmospherically correcting it yourself, or just use uncorrected data for your study.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen It worked with self correction. Thank you.